# The Meteor poll time is config

Tags: meteor

the meteor poll time is configurable in server app ? 
I need delay poll for masive updates to database.

How config this time for balancing massive updates ?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by poll time?

Comment: Looks like it's hardcoded : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo/polling_observe_driver.js#L64

Comment: Meteor use polling o tail oplog for reactive update. The polling time is 10 seconds by default. Can I change this time ?